# Can an argument be passed to enumerate (or other list command) that tells it how many items are to be in the list?

Tags: lists, enumerate, itemize

I would like to create a numbered (or bulletized) list but would like the number of items in the list to be variable. I would like the variable to be read in from an external file. For example, the first time though there would be 4 items, the next time 6 items, etc. My test case is for writing procedures in a series of steps (i.e. items in a list) to accomplish a specific goal. Can this be done exclusively with LaTeX commands?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. This is no feature of the `enumerate` etc. environments and I know of no package that allows for this. The problem is not the number of items, the problem is the item itself, i.e. `\item` **foo**... Do you want to fetch **foo** from the file as well?

Comment: Yes.  Here's a text file sample:

Comment: 1. Turn on PDU.

Comment: 2. Look for ready light. etc.

Comment: The next time I read in the steps there may be more (or less) steps but I don't know that prior to running (compiling) the latex script.

Comment: It isn't clear from your description why you need anything other than `\begim{itemize}` with a variable number of `\item` ?

Comment: I am creating a 'generic' latex doc that will read in text files created by test case developers. These text files will have varying numbers of steps (i.e. items) depending on what is being tested. I will only know the number of steps for each test case when I read in the text file. Does \begin{itemize} allow for variable numbers of items to be read? If so how is that accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A version with `expl3` features and storing the individual lines in a sequence that is displayed later on.

First use `\ReadFromFile{filename}{listname}` where `listname` can be basically any word. This will read the individual lines into a `expl3` `\seq` variable.

Later on, use `\DisplayList{listname}` inside of an `enumerate` or `itemize` environment. With the help of `enumitem` package the item labels can be easily changed.

The storage allows for redisplay later on, if needed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{xparse}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\ior_new:N \l_t_king_file
\cs_new:Nn \t_king_readfromfile:nn {%
  \seq_gput_right:cn {g_#1_t_king_item_seq} {#2}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ReadFromFile}{mm}{%
  \seq_if_exist:cTF {g_#2_t_king_item_seq } 
  {
    \seq_gclear:c {g_#2_t_king_item_seq}
  }{%
    \seq_gclear_new:c {g_#2_t_king_item_seq}
  }
  % Open the file from arg #1
  \ior_open:Nn \l_t_king_file {#1} 
  % Read its content to the #2 - named variable
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \l_t_king_file {\t_king_readfromfile:nn {#2} {##1}}
  % Close the file
  \ior_close:N   \l_t_king_file
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\DisplayList}{m}{%
  \seq_map_inline:cn {g_#1_t_king_item_seq} {\item ##1}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\ReadFromFile{shortitems.txt}{myfirstlist}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\Roman*)}]
  \DisplayList{myfirstlist}
\end{enumerate}

\ReadFromFile{longerlist.txt}{myotherlist}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\Alph*)}]
  \DisplayList{myotherlist}
\end{enumerate}

Redisplay with usual numbers:

\begin{enumerate}
  \DisplayList{myotherlist}
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

The files `shortitems.txt` and `longerlist.txt` contain the lines

> Turn on PDU
>
> Look for ready light

or

> Turn on PDU
>
> Look for ready light
>
> Mix the drinks
>
> Serve the drinks
>
> Enjoy the drinks

[image]